# text color in HTML MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Here's the program which checks status of customer's parcel in switch loop. There's a couple different statuses and I'd like to show them in different colors. Here's a loop with example case:

```
switch (Parcel.Status) {
    case Customer.enSOMAccountIsEmpty:
        parcel.Comment = status.Comment;
        break;
    ...
}
```

In Model I created two types of colors in class Parcel:

```
public class Parcel {
    public string StatusColor { get; set; }
    public string CommentColor { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, the kode in View:

```
<body>
    <div>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ParcelList)
        {
            <p>
                @item.StatusText
            </p>
            <p>
                @item.Comment
            </p>
            <p>
                @item.InfoDate
            </p>
        }
    </div>
</body>
```

How to connect these types from Models to View to show every status in different color? For example status from first case has red color becouse "Account is Empty" and comment to it should be blue. Thanks.

Comment: How are you storing the Colour in the StatusColour ? is it Hex, or RGB or a Colour string such as `blue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the status colour in the switch.

```
case Customer.enSOMAccountIsEmpty:
                        parcel.Comment = status.Comment;
                        parcel.StatusColor = "red";
                        break;
```

and then in your view you can

```
<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ParcelList)
    {
        <p style='color:@item.StatusColor'>
            @item.StatusText
        </p>
        <p style='color:@item.StatusColor'>
            @item.Comment
        </p>
        <p style='color:@item.StatusColor'>
            @item.InfoDate
        </p>
    }

</div>
```

I believe this is what you are requesting?

Comment: Looks good Kallen. We are assuming StatusColor is in the form of '#0000FF' or 'Blue'. Defined colour names are here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp

Comment: Yes of course, as long as in the switch you set the string to a valid defined colour name then all will be good :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
@{
if(string.IsnullOrEmpty(item.StatusText))
<span style="background:red">Text</span>

@else
<span style="background:blue">Text</span>

}
```

Where this is the check with the behalf of we will choose color, you can change it accordingly.